# How to read specific variables from the string using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, input

There is a file which has this content

```
   SomeText1

   SomeCommand -parameterName abc -login def -password geh

   SomeText2
```

Could you please advise what PowerShell should be in order to read into the array the variables and values (may be like key/value pair) for

```
 login=def
 password=geh
```

The specific about that question is that the order of the login and password parameters may be different, so I need to find the way how to locate the key/value based on the known key name. Also, I know that I need only login and password parameters and associated values.

Thank you very much for your help, in advance!

P.S. I was planning to use the following commands to read the file content, but that can be changed:

```
$GetFileName = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Folder\Input.txt" 

$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($GetFileName)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Select-String` cmdlet offers a convenient way to use regular expressions to extract information from files:

```
$inputFile = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Folder\Input.txt"

# Extract the information of interest and output it as a hashtable.
# Use $ht = Select-String ... to capture the hashtable in a variable.
Select-String -Allmatches '(?<=-(login|password) +)[^ ]+' $inputFile |
  ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($match in $_.Matches) {
      @{ $match.Groups[1] = $match.Value }
    }
  }
```

With the sample input, the output is a single hashtable (if multiple lines match, you'll get a hashtable for each line):

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
login                          def
password                       geh
```

- `-AllMatches` tells `Select-String` to search for multiple matches on each line.
- Regex `'(?<=-(login|password) +)[^ ]+'` captures the argument associated with parameters `-login` and `-password`, while capturing the parameter name in a capture group.

  - Note that the regex assumes that the argument values have no embedded spaces, but that is usually a safe assumption in usernames and passwords.
- `foreach ($match in $_.Matches)` processes each match, and constructs and outputs a hashtable (`@{ ... }` ) whose key is the captured parameter name, and whose value is the captured argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to do this.  For examle, here is how you can pull the parameters and arguments from a command string and output them as a custom object (for easy manipulation later):

```
$cmd = "Some-Command -ParameterOne abc -ParameterTwo def -ParameterThree geh -SwitchParameter"

[Regex]::Matches($cmd, "-(?<param>\w+) (?<arg>\w*)|-(?<param>\w+)") |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Parameter = $_.Groups['param'].Value
            Argument = $_.Groups['arg'].Value
        }
    }
```

The output is like this:

```
Parameter       Argument
---------       --------
ParameterOne    abc     
ParameterTwo    def     
ParameterThree  geh     
SwitchParameter
```

Something like `Get-Content` might be suitable for reading the command from the file in the first place.